# Generalization of Multiplicity for System of Non Linear Equations

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

I was doing some simulations for the solution of a system of Non-Linear Equations using Newton Method and found that the convergence is linear. I went through the literature for Newton method and found that this behavior is expected for equations having a root of multiplicity greater that one.

How do we define the idea of the multiplicity of a solution for a Non-Linear system of equations? And how do we check that if the system of non-linear equations has a solution whose multiplicity is greater than one?

Comment: $x^2=0$ is a nonlinear equation and its root has multiplicity two. I don't understand why you expect them to be linear? In fact, a nonconstant linear equation always has root with multiplicity 1.

Comment: The system of equations, plus I wrote convergence is linear.

Comment: The Newton method is not guaranteed to have better-than-linear convergence if the Jacobian matrix at the solution is singular.

Comment: If the matrix is singular then the method fails. I want to know can we generalize the idea of multiplicity for a system of non-linear equations?

Comment: Generalize from what?

Comment: From one dimension case. We say $a$ is a multiple root of $f(x)$ if $f(a)=f'(a)=0$. So, can we say the same for system of non linear equations?

Comment: So you willingly accept that the Jacobian matrix in the one-dimensional case can be singular (i.e. $f'(a)=0$), but there is a problem if the Jacobian in the multi-dimensional case is singular?

Comment: Sorry on my behalf. But here is what I am confused about, in multi dimension case we solve a system of the form $A(x)x=b$, hence if $\tilde{x}$ is the solution of the system, should we have $DA(x)(\tilde x)=0$ or $DA(x)(\tilde x)=b$ as the case for multiple roots? Where $DA(x)$ is the Jacobian

Comment: Regarding the "multiple root analogy": If $J$ is the Jacobian matrix of $f$ at the point $\bar x$ and $J$ is singular, then there exists a vector $v$ with $Jv=0.$ All functions $f_1,\ldots,f_n,$ have (in a manner of speaking) a multiple root at $\bar x$ in the direction of $v,$ i.e. the one-dimensional functions $h\mapsto f_i(\bar x+hv)$ have a multiple root at $0.$

Comment: Regarding the order of convergence: The system $(Df(x))\cdot \Delta x = f(x)$ can usually be solved even if $Df(\bar x)$ is singular, just because we do not use $Df(\bar x)$ but $Df(x).$ The problem is that $Df(x)$ is "nearly singular", because it is close to $Df(\bar x),$ which corrupts the convergence.